# Create Multidex Main Dex Class List

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am not using proguard although I have MultiDex enabled. The whole Xamarin solution builds but I keep getting the following in the output window of Visual Studio 2017.

> CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource
>   [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry
>   [android-support-multidex.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
>   CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource
>   [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry
>   [SfChart.Android.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
>   CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource
>   [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry
>   [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST :
>   warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip
>   entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
>   CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource
>   [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry
>   [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST :
>   warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip
>   entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])

I am using Xamarin 4.5.0.486
Xamarin.Android 7.3.1.2
Xamarin.IOS 10.10.0.37

I deleted the bin and obj folders and did a rebuild but that didn't fix the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a demo? So I can reproduce the problem, thanks!